# "Empty" container to set as another UI element's parent

Tags: android, xml

I'm re-writing my app with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55635684/2016165) layout in Android (using Android Studio 3.6 & Java 8) and noticed that I can't directly set the background color of an `EditText` or `Spinner` because the background used contains the e.g. `EditText`'s line (the line the text is written on).

To work around that in my iOS app I simply gave that UI element (with an otherwise transparent background) a `View` parent that uses the right background color. In Android Studio this works the same way if I use an e.g. `LinearLayout` as parent but I don't need that layout's full functionality and I'm worried that "abusing" `LinearLayout`s like this multiple times might affect performance.

There is a `View` widget in Android Studio but it's not possible to add an `EditText` or `Spinner` as its child.

Are there any layouts/views that can be added via Android Studio's UI builder or through xml and that act as the "empty" container I need? What's the best layout to use performance-wise?

Comment: try setting  "backgrund" attribute of Edittext with color, i am sure it will work

Comment: @KhalidSaeed That's what I tried first but it doesn't work for the reason I already mentioned in the question: The background of an `EditText` contains the "line" its text is written on. To be exact, it's the `edit_text_material`, which is an Android drawable. If I set a background color instead, the `EditText` turns e.g. red but the line is gone and the element changes height. This ["problem"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18693639/2016165) also comes up as the very first search result.

Comment: in that case you can set height and width to match_parent then it will cover the whole box

Comment: @KhalidSaeed I know but as soon as I get rid of the existing background/material, the line at the bottom is gone, which means that there's no indication that it's even an `EditText` that can be clicked into. To change the background color, you either have to create a custom `EditText` (pretty sure there's already code for that) or use the trick I'm currently using and that takes advantage of the UI element's transparency (which doesn't require someone else's code).